# Compute variance of a power Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, poisson-process

> Let $N_t$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. Let $X_t = (1+a)^{N_t}$. Compute
>   $Var((1+a)^{N_t})$.

My attempt:

First I tried to compute the MGF, but I could not simplify it.

Then I try to compute it by definition:

$Var(X_t) = E[(1+a)^{2N_t}] - (E[(1+a)^{N_t}])^2$

I can easily compute:
$E[(1+a)^{N_t}] = e^{\lambda t a}$

But I cannot simplify the quantity:

$$E[(1+a)^{2N_t}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1+a)^{2k} \dfrac{(\lambda t)^k e^{-\lambda t}}{k!} =e^{-\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1+a)^{2k} \dfrac{(\lambda t)^k }{k!}$$

How can I compute this sum? There must be some clever way!

Comment: $(1+a)^{2k} = ((1+a)^2)^k$. So you get $\frac{((1+a)^2(\lambda t))^k}{k!}$, which the infinite sum is just $e^{(1+a)^2(\lambda t))}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+a)^{2k}\frac{(λt)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left((1+a)^2λt\right)^k}{k!}=e^{(1+a)^2λt}$$